# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' python

Tags: python

I run the following code:

```
import sys
def find_common(a,b,c):
    d=[]
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            d=d.append(i)
    for i in d:
        if i not in c:
            c=c.append(i)
    print(c)
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=[1,1,2,4]
    b=[2,2,3,4]
    c=[]
    find_common(a,b,c)
    sys.exit()
```

but get the following error:

```
d=d.append(i)  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why is it happening? Please help to fix it.

Comment: You have reassigned `d` with the return value of `d.append`, which is `None`, resulting in the error.  You do not need to assign the return value of `list.append` to some variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`d.append(i)` returns `None`
therefore:
`d = d.append(i)` assigns `None` to `d`

replace that line with:
`d.append(i)`

The same goes for `c = c.append(i)`

Answer (score 2):

first you don't need to reassign the d

```
d=d.append(sth)


import sys
def find_common(a,b,c):
    d=[]
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            d=d.append(i)
    for i in d:
        if i not in c:
            c=c.append(i)
    print(c)
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a=[1,1,2,4]
    b=[2,2,3,4]
    c=[]
    find_common(a,b,c)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: although it is rather inconsistent, `c` is already defined in `main`

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to repeat what the others have already said when it comes to `append()` returning `None`, but I will suggest a shorter solution, which works with arbitrary number of arguments:

```
def find_common(*args):
    return list(set.intersection(*[set(arg) for arg in args]))

>>> a = [1, 3, 2, 4]
>>> b = [2, 2, 3, 4]
>>> c = [3, 3, 4, 5]
>>> d = [1, 4, 7, 6]
>>> find_common(a, b, c, d)
[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you are reassigning d.append() to d.

d.append() returns None.

```
d = []
print d.append(4) #None
```

So change your code to following and it will work.

```
def find_common(a,b,c):
    d=[]
    for i in a:
        if i in b:
            d.append(i)
    for i in d:
        if i not in c:
            c.append(i)
    print(c)
    return c
```