# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. How to append int to list in a loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to add an `int` to a `list` in a **loop**. The below code works well:

```
p = []
p.append(3)
```

But, when i run this code:

```
p = [] 
for x in range(24):
    p = p.append(3)
    print(p)
```

I face with the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Meanwhile, i expect to have a list with length of 24.

So, why i am not able to add the 3s to the list?

Comment: Don't reassign `p`. Just do the append call without `p =`. `append` returns `None`.

Comment: A quick search of your exception message would have turned up this post ['NoneType' object has no attribute 'append' python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578288/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-append-python), along with multiple others. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` does not return a `list`, it changes the state of the list on which it's called. Therefore, when you assign `p = p.append(3)`, you're assigning `p` the value of `None`, and hence you get the error you cited.

To fix this, simply eliminate the assignment in the loop.

```
p = [] 
for x in range(24):
    p.append(3)
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** assign. Just use the `append` method. If you assign then `p` becomes `None`.

Use this:

```
p = [] 
for x in range(24):
    p.append(3)
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can also do this without using a full loop and `append`ing:

Multiplying a list `[3]` by `24`:

```
[3] * 24
```

A list comprehension:

```
[3 for _ in range(24)]
```

Or to be  fancy `itertools.repeat`:

```
repeat(3, 24)
```

Or using numpy:

```
np.full(24, 3)
```

See below:

```
>>> p = [] 
>>> for x in range(24):
...     p.append(3)
>>> p
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> [3]*24
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> [3 for _ in range(24)]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> list(repeat(3, 24))
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> list(np.full(24, 3))
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```